# Magento 2 Header Search Border on Focus

Tags: magento-2.1, search, header

How can i set disable the glowing blue border on focus from the Header Search (minisearch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just CSS issue. The original style added a `box-shadow` when you focus on any input boxes. So, add the following code into your theme CSS.

```
input#search:focus:not([disabled]){
    box-shadow: none
}
```

It will disable the `box-shadow` on the header search(aka mini-search).