# How can I disable the glowing blue border on focus from all input fileds

Tags: css, frontend, input, magento2.4.1

I wonder if you could help.
I would like to disable the glowwing blue border on focus from all my input fields and replace it with border-bottom: 1px solid black.

I found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180141/magento-2-header-search-border-on-focus)

`input#search:focus:not([disabled]){ box-shadow: none }`

I added to the css
`border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;`

so now I have
`input#search:focus:not([disabled]) { box-shadow: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a; }`

Then I added it to my _extend.less file app/frontend/vendor/theme/web/cs/source
and it works as required but only for the search bar input. I would like to do it for all my input fields.

Please give me a tip on how to do it.

Thank you in advance.
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

According with Magento2 best practices you can override the variable @focus__box-shadow in your variable.less in your theme.
In your theme folder /web/css/source/_variable.less
set

```
@focus__box-shadow: none;
```